# Changing Color of Path Guides in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Not sure if "path" is the right term here... I'm trying to change the color of the outline in Illustrator when using the pen tool. My border is set to black and the background of the artboard is white however the guide or outline is yellow. How can I change this yellow color?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Double click the layer in the Layers Panel Or Choose Layer Options from the Layer Panel menu. You then have a choice of colors to use.

[image]

Comment: Ahh that's right, the yellow color has been staring at me from the layer all along, can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and followed @SOIA's answer. However, I wanted to clarify it on the new version, and because I didn't know where to click, and ended up spending a while on it.

so you have to click on Layers (1), then double click on layer n (2), but on the grey area, not the name or the image.

[image]